# Jquery .css() function trouble with unicode character

Tags: jquery, html, css

Here is a link to the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ekimm2/LcLAA/

When I try to color one of the unicode stars upon clicking, nothing happens. I'm sure its something trivial but I cant seem to fix it. Any thoughts? I put the javascript below, but the rest I left in the jsfiddle for simplicity purposes.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.stars').click( function()     
    {
        $(this).css('color', 'ffd700')
    });
});
```

Edit: Sorry about that, I had to make an account, it should be fixed now

Comment: You linked to a blank fiddle.

Comment: Your JSFiddle is empty.

Comment: Sorry, I fixed the op with the right jsfiddle

Comment: @user1835351 your fiddle is completely different to your question

Comment: @user1835351 most of it, i have updated my answer with a fiddle for you, also your fiddle does not include a jQuery library

Comment: Did any of our answers help?

Comment: Yep, I followed your suggestions and I fixed it, I was screwing up the jquery with the document load, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were a few problems with your javascript and fiddle. See **[this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LcLAA/7/)** which is an update of yours with problems fixed. Problems were:

1. Using prevall caused wrong stars to be coloured.
2. Not colouring current star.
3. Not including jquery dropdown in fiddle.
4. Using document.ready and load dropdown.
5. Stars covered by Result tag in fiddle window caused hover and click to not work.

I have changed to add `margin-top:10%;` and use `nextAll` and set the colour on the current element.

Answer (score 1):

Use a hash(#) for colour and add a semicolon(;).

```
$(this).css('color', '#ffd700');
```

See [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LcLAA/3/).

Comment: @Bigood i agree but i have run into situation in JavaScript where not having it has caused an error :)

Comment: I added those, but it still doesnt change the color

Answer (score 0):

Using a hash **does** works, as Ashley mentioned it.

If you include jQuery in your fiddle, and remove your `$(document).ready()`, it barely works (I mean, the color is changing, but not the way you intended it).

I think the actual problem is not the color, but the fact you're misusing `prevAll()`, as your elements are floated right. [See this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LcLAA/4/).

*Note : You might either reconsider your question, or amend an edit, so we could help you & stay in the question's scope if you wish. Either, I'll move this to a comment.*